# Scale and data precision

Tags: georeferencing, scale, resolution

In the metadata of a database containing locations of natural hazards, it appears that the accuracy of the georeferencing of each point is associated with a scale of 1:10,000.

How can I associate this 1:10 000 scale with spacial precision?

Since 1:10 000 is associated with a 5 meter raster resolution ([link](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/product/imagery/on-map-scale-and-raster-resolution/)), does this mean that the error associated with the point location is related to the spatial resolution?

So it is right to say that each point could be at maximum 5 meters off the correct location?

Comment: My take on this is that you have to assume a minimal error of 5 meter not maximum (if you plot thing on a 5m raster you cant get more accurate than 5m). If your data are derived from an 1/10 000 scale map that mean an 0.5mm error while digitizing translate to 5m of position error...